# drop-down menu not opening in single click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

pop-up menu not working in a single click can any one help me to this?

Here is the link 
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/swarupsrk/4yd7panj/)

Here is the image

[image]

Please help me open it on single click and hide on anywhere click in the body.

Here is the Code

```
    $(function () {
    $('.ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li').tooltip();
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-bar").click(function (e) {
        /*e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }*/
    });

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-user").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-doctor").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-patient").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-settings").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-import").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");      //Add Class Active
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not really a question, more just "debug my code!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of unnecessary code in your JS. Also the references to the external sources were not correctly put up. Here is the updated JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {       

    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) { 
            //$(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");        //Add Class Active
        }
        else { 
            $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active");       //Remove Class Active
        }
    });
});
```

Also remove the class `clearfix` from your HTML like this:

```
<div class="ui-323 active" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 100;">
    <!-- Your code -->
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

Add the following JS code for closing the menu items on mouseleave:

```
 $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a").mouseleave(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active");
 });
```

I have updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yd7panj/7/). Now the menu items are opening up in a single click and closing on mouseleave.

Comment: Its Working but its hide when i going to click the link.i can't click the link

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of unnecessary duplicate code in there. I'd simplify all those click functions down to one, then add the class "menuItem" to each link. I edited your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/4yd7panj/3/

It wasn't working also because jsfiddle wasn't able to pull those files. I added the regular jQuery and disabled your tooltips to show how the thing works.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.menuItem").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents(".ui-323").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

You could make this simpler by making it toggleClass...  Actually, yeah, there's no reason not to.  Edited the answer.